# Can't add Azure AD Admins to Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server with Private access (VNet Integration)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-postgresql

I have created in my Azure subscription two instances of Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server.Let me call them **server01-psql** and **server02-psql**
They both

- are in the same Resource group, let me call it **app-rg**
- run POstgreSQL version **14**
- are created with Authentication method: **PostgreSQL and Azure Active Directory authentication**

The difference is only

- **server01-psql** | Networking > Connectivity method: Private access (VNet Integration) to a VNet and Subnet from the same Azure subscription
- **server02-psql** | Networking > Connectivity method: Public access (allowed IP addresses)

I want to add chosen Azure AD group, let me call it *all-app-dbadm*, as Azure Active Directory Administrators (Azure AD Admins) for both instances of Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server.

My account is Owner of the subscription and my account is also Global Administrator of the related Azure Active Directory.

I can successfully add group from related Tenant to **server02-psql** in section **Authentication > Azure Active Directory Administrators (Azure AD Admins)**

However if I try to use

- portal.azure.com
  [image: Azure AD Admins in portal.azure.com]
- or az-cli
  `az postgres flexible-server ad-admin create -g app-rg -s server01-psql -u mysupergroup -i mysupergroupguid -t Group`
  I allways get an error.
  `Deployment to resource group 'app-rg' failed. Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details. The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.  (Code: ResourceDeploymentFailure, Target: /subscriptions/mysupersubscriptionid/resourceGroups/app-rg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/addAdmins-0-XXXXXX)`

Could you recommend what needs to be changed on any of the related resources, or perhaps at the subscription level, or in the process of the change to add successfully **Azure Active Directory Administrators (Azure AD Admins)** to **server01-psql**?

Comment: Please check the deployment logs under the resource group (RG -> Deployments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same error while setting the AD group as the AD admin in the Azure database for PostgreSQL flexible server, as mentioned below:

[image]

To resolve the issue, I added an outbound network security group (NSG) rule to allow virtual network traffic to only reach the `AzureActiveDirectory` service tag, as mentioned below:

[image]

[image]

I attempted to set the admin using the following command in Azure CLI:

```
az postgres flexible-server ad-admin create -g <resourceGroupName> -s <serverName> -u <AD Group> -i <AD groupId> -t Group
```

It executed successfully without any errors, as mentioned below:

[image]

The admin was added successfully to the server, as mentioned below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication?source=recommendations#prerequisites).

Comment: Thank you. In my case I had to additionally follow "If you're using a route table, you need to create a rule with destination service tag AzureActiveDirectory and next hop Internet." as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication?source=recommendations#prerequisites